# How do I put a condition on msbuild built-in targets like Build/Rebuild?

Tags: build, msbuild, azure-devops, azure-pipelines, csproj

I am working differentially building a huge monolithic solution that includes about 80 projects. In my build pipeline right now I include a step to build the entire solution. But what I'd like to do is to build the solution but provide conditions as msbuild arguments so that I can exclude some of the projects that might not have any changes associated with them. I already have scripts to go through my commits and realize what changed and which projects need to be built.

I just need a way to send that info to MSBuild so that it does not build all projects everytime. I tried building projects separately but that takes a whole lot more time than just building the solution together.

So, I'm looking for any solutions out there through which I can specify to MSBuild that skip a specific project would help a lot. Thanks much!

Comment: Typically you would create a new configuration, and if using an MSBuild deploy task pass this into the Configuration box. See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/visualstudio/ide/how-to-exclude-projects-from-a-build?view=vs-2015&redirectedfrom=MSDN

Comment: @Michael Thanks, what projects I'd need to exclude from the build is calculated on the fly right before the build step in my pipeline, so there is not a specific project that I know I don't need to build all the time. The projects would depend on the changes/commits for that build. So, I'd need a way to dynamically build or skip a project while building the solution!

Comment: Could it be easier in your scenario to calulcate which projects you actually need? You could then create a temporary solution on the fly containing these projects. `dotnet sln` can also add/remove project files to/from solutions.

Comment: I would rather not want to do that as there is a huge number of projects in my solution about 80. That I think will be more time taking than skip building some projects.

Comment: In that case could you create a PowerShell task and call MSBuild? Int that instance you could pass in a list of projects which could be set at build time. https://www.powershellgallery.com/packages/Invoke-MsBuild/2.6.2

Comment: Hi @Michael thanks for the suggestions. Yes, I did try to run parallel PS Jobs for just building the projects that I want to. But that gets into weird issues when some projects are dependent on the same projects I guess MSBuild can't work though those. SO, I found building Solution as a whole a better solution

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I already have scripts to go through my commits and realize what
>   changed and which projects need to be built.

Since I could get clearly know that which script are you using to realize what changed and which projects need to be built. I am assuming that you are using MSbuildTarget script which in the `xx.csproj` to do these judgement.

=If I did not have misunderstanding, you can get help from this [similar issue](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/fca13e7e-7211-4af5-baad-4b58749a333e/how-to-skip-building-the-current-project-and-move-on-to-the-next-one-in-the-prebuild-event?forum=msbuild) (See **ilya's** answer).

See [this document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/msbuild/how-to-extend-the-visual-studio-build-process?view=vs-2019#override-dependson-properties) and you'll find the build action is performed by these three targets, BeforeBuild,CoreBuild and AfterBuild. So assuming you have a target to go through my commits and realize what changed and if a project need to be built, you can add script like below to `xx.csproj`:

```
<PropertyGroup>
    <BuildWrapperDependsOn>$(BuildDependsOn)</BuildWrapperDependsOn>
    <BuildDependsOn>CheckIfBuildIsNeeded;BuildWrapper</BuildDependsOn>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <Target Name="CheckIfBuildIsNeeded">
    <!-- Execute command here that checks if proceed with the build and sets the exit code -->
    <Exec Command="exit /b 1" WorkingDirectory="$(SourcesPath)" IgnoreExitCode="true">   
      <Output TaskParameter="ExitCode" PropertyName="ExecExitCode"/>
    </Exec>
    <Message Text="Exit Code: $(ExecExitCode)" Importance="high" />
    <PropertyGroup Condition="'$(ExecExitCode)' == '1'">
      <DoBuild>false</DoBuild>
    </PropertyGroup>
  </Target>

  <Target Name="BuildWrapper" Condition=" '$(DoBuild)' != 'false' " DependsOnTargets="$(BuildWrapperDependsOn)" Returns="$(TargetPath)" />
```

Above is the script from **ilys**, and hope my description can help you understand it. With this script, when we start a build target, it will firstly run the targets it depends on, so it will run the CheckIfBuildIsNeeded target and BuildWrapper target. And only when the DoBuild property is true, the BuildWrapper will actually execute. And since buildwrapper depends on original $(BuildDependsOn), it will continue the real build process.

The total logic is: Run CheckIfBuildIsNeeded script and output value to indicates whether need to build=>Try to Run BuildWrapper=>IF need to build, then run the real build success(BeforeBuild, Corebuild,Afterbuild), if the value is false, finish the build process. So I think you can do some little changes to this script then it can work for your situation. (Not sure what your script looks like, I can't complete it for you)

And since you have many projects, you don't need to add this script to every project manually. You can create a [Directory.Build.props](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/msbuild/customize-your-build?view=vs-2019#directorybuildprops-and-directorybuildtargets) file, copy the script into it, and place the file in solution folder, then it will work for all projects in the solution.

Comment: Thanks @Merlin Liang, this is what I want to effectively do but in a task that's building the Solution file and not just a projet. Hopefully this works for that as well. I am going to try this solution though and comment when I have some progress. Thank You!

Comment: @codester, how the things going? Does the script could help you build the solution file successfully? Feel free to leave comment if you have some other issues thus we can help you further.

Comment: unfortunately, the Exit code strategy exits the entire msbuild process which is building the solution. So, the build fails as the other projects I want to build could not be built! This is the error! `##[error]Process 'msbuild.exe' exited with code '1'.`

Comment: @codester. Exit code '1' is a very general error code. You'd better share the full debug log~ It should has some key error message.

Comment: so I had to update all of the other csproj files for Test Projects to works with this and with that update it seems to work on my local and I'm now in works to get it to work thru VSTS build pipelines.

Comment: @codester It must be a very large work to finish update all the csproj file  In fact, there has another every easy method is that create a Directory.Build.props file, put the script into it then place this file in the solution folder.

Comment: @codester But still glad it works with the build pipeline:-)

Comment: I need these properties to be specific to the Project that I'm building to be able to set them one way or the other, so there would need to be custom logic placed in each of the csprojs and that is why I needed to update those that need that specific property/logic! Thanks for the help though!